# Not navigating to a webpage after completion

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have just changed the way a user enters data, from using `<h:` to `<:p` from the primefaces library, and now when the data has been successfully added to the database it no longer automatically takes the user to relevent pages. The only changes I have made is instead of using the code below to enter data:

```
<h:messages showDetail="true" /> 

<h:outputText value="Enter Name : " />
<h:inputText value="#{user.name}" />
<br></br>               
<h:outputText value="Enter email address : "/>
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{user.email}" 
    size="20" required="true" label="Email Address">
  <f:validator validatorId="richard.test.EmailValidator" />
</h:inputText>
<br></br>
<h:outputText value="Enter your address : "/>
<h:inputText value="#{user.address}" />   
<br></br>

<h:outputText value="Enter Created Date : "/>
<h:inputText value="#{user.created_date}">
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</h:inputText>
<br></br>

<br></br>
<h:message for="email" style="color:red" />

<h:commandButton value="Insert" action="#{user.add}"/>
```

The above code still works if I run that instead of the code below:

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />

    <p:panel header="Growl">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Enter Name : " />
            <h:inputText value="#{user.name}" required="true" />

            <h:outputText value="Enter email address : " />
            <h:inputText id="email" value="#{user.email}" size="20" required="true" label="Email Address">
                <f:validator validatorId="richard.test.EmailValidator" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="Enter your address : " />
            <h:inputText value="#{user.address}" />

            <h:outputText value="Enter Created Date : " />
            <h:inputText value="#{user.created_date}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
            </h:inputText>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{user.add}" update="growl" />
    </p:panel>
</h:form>

<h:form>
    <h:messages showDetail="true" />
</h:form>
```

The reason behind the change was to make a better look for the user, but while it looks professional and adds all the data to the database it no longer sends the user to a page is successful etc, although the `faces-config.xml` file has not changed. The only change is the use of primefaces. What would be causing this, and is there a way on successful input of data to take the user to the right page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your p:commandButton invokes `user.add` as actionListener instead of action like the h:commandButton in your first example. Simply switch to action, that should lead to the behaviour you want it to have.

Comment: Was anything wrong about my answer (that was posted some minutes earlier)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of JSF's implicit navigation change `actionListener`-attribute in your `<p:commandButton>` to `action`. That's it.